# Unable to find dnssd headers error while trying to install a ruby gem

Tags: ruby, macos

Getting this error

```
ERROR:  Error installing dnssd:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p550/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20141108-39945-13la3bu.rb extconf.rb
checking for dns_sd.h... no
unable to find dnssd header
*** extconf.rb failed ***

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p550@kevy/gems/dnssd-2.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p550@kevy/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/1.9.1/dnssd-2.0/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing dnssd (2.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install dnssd -v '2.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I'm running yosemite osx so the header file is there by default. I found it at /usr/include/dns_sd.h.

Short of reinstalling operating system is there any way to fix?

Thanks

Comment: Did you update XCode command line tools?

Comment: Yes. XCode is up to date.

Comment: A clean install did not fix the issue.

Comment: "XCode" or "XCode Command Line Tools"? It is important

Comment: I'm also running into this issue, I've tried updating the xcode command line tools and it hasn't resolved the problem

Comment: i ended up just having to update to ruby 2.0.0

Answer (score 0):

On my ubuntu system, I also meet this problem.

```
eric@Ideapad:~$ gem install ahoy
Fetching ahoy-0.1.4.gem
Fetching xmpp4r-0.5.gem
Fetching dnssd-3.0.2.gem
Successfully installed xmpp4r-0.5
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing ahoy:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /home/eric/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.0/gems/dnssd-3.0.2/ext/dnssd
/home/eric/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.3.0/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for dns_sd.h... no
unable to find dnssd header
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may need configuration options.
```

Then I install **libavahi-compat-libdnssd-dev**, like this:

```
sudo apt install libavahi-compat-libdnssd-dev
```

when you finish this step, you can

```
eric@Ideapad:~$ gem install ahoy
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
Successfully installed dnssd-3.0.2
Successfully installed ahoy-0.1.4
Parsing documentation for dnssd-3.0.2
Installing ri documentation for dnssd-3.0.2
Parsing documentation for ahoy-0.1.4
Installing ri documentation for ahoy-0.1.4
Done installing documentation for dnssd, ahoy after 0 seconds
2 gems installed
```